# Binary selection process

Tags: python, c, algorithm, binary-search

I have been working on what seems to be a simple task that is driving me nuts. So if you fancy a programming challenge ... read on.

I want to be able to take a number range e.g. [1:20] and print the values using a mechanism similar to a binary serach algorithm. So, print first the lowest value (in this case 1) and then the mid value (e.g. in this case 10) and then divide the range into quarters and print the values at 1/4 and 3/4 (in this case, 5 and 15) and then divide into eights and so on until all values in the range have been printed.

The application of this (which isn't really necessary to understand here) is for a memory page access mechanism that behaves more efficiently when pages are accessed at the mid ranges first.

For this problem, it would be sufficient to take any number range and print the values in the manner described above.

Any thoughts on this? A psuedo code solution would be fine. I would show an attempt to this but everything I've tried so far doesn't cut it. Thanks.

Update: As requested, the desired output for the example [1:20] would be something like this: 1, 10, 5, 15, 3, 7, 12, 17, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 13, 16, 18, 9, 19, 20

This output could be presented in many similar ways depending on the algorithm used. But, the idea is to display first the half values, then the quarters, then the eights, then 16ths, etc leaving out previously presented values.

Comment: Could you please provide the desired complete output for a sample case?

Comment: but you can only use pages that you allocate am i right?

Comment: This answer to similar question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11761192/1009831

Comment: Please ignore the the memory page allocation aspect to the problem since it won't be a familiar problem.

Comment: It seems to me to be a mistake to start the sequence at `1` since every other output is a midpoint.

Comment: @MarkRansom, You could well be correct. I am open to starting with the midpoint also.

Comment: what kind of runtime are you looking for? O(nlgn)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is some Python code producing similar output to your example:

```py
def f(low, high):
    ranges = collections.deque([(low, high)])
    while ranges:
        low, high = ranges.popleft()
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        yield mid
        if low < mid:
            ranges.append((low, mid))
        if mid + 1 < high:
            ranges.append((mid + 1, high))
```

Example:

```
>>> list(f(0, 20))
[10, 5, 15, 2, 8, 13, 18, 1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 14, 17, 19, 0, 3, 6, 11, 16]
```

The `low, high` range excludes the endpoint, as is convention in Python, so the result contains the numbers from 0 to 19.

The code uses a FIFO to store the subranges that still need to be processed.  The FIFO is initialised with the full range.  In each iteration, the next range is popped and the mid-point yielded.  Then, the lower and upper subrange of the current range is appended to the FIFO if they are non-empty.

**Edit**: Here is a completely different implementation in C99:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const unsigned n = 20;
    for (unsigned i = 1; n >> (i - 1); ++i) {
        unsigned last = n;    // guaranteed to be different from all x values
        unsigned count = 1;
        for (unsigned j = 1; j < (1 << i); ++j) {
            const unsigned x = (n * j) >> i;
            if (last == x) {
                ++count;
            } else {
                if (count == 1 && !(j & 1)) {
                    printf("%u\n", last);
                }
                count = 1;
                last = x;
            }
        }
        if (count == 1)
            printf("%u\n", last);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This avoids the necessity of a FIFO by using some tricks to determine if an integer has already occured in an earlier iteration.

You could also easily implement the original solution in C.  Since you know the maximum size of the FIFO (I guess it's something like (n+1)/2, but you would need to double check this), you can use a ring buffer to hold the queued ranges.

**Edit 2**: Here is yet another solution in C99.  It is optimised to do only half the loop iterations and to use only bit oprations and additions, no multiplication or divisions.  It's also more succinct, and it does not include `0` in the results, so you can have this go at the beginning as you initially intended.

```
for (int i = 1; n >> (i - 1); ++i) {
    const int m = 1 << i;
    for (int x = n; x < (n << i); x += n << 1) {
        const int k = x & (m - 1);
        if (m - n <= k && k < n)
            printf("%u\n", x >> i);
    }
}
```

(This is the code I intended to write right from the beginning, but it took me some time to wrap my head around it.)

Comment: That looks pretty sweet. I will give that approach a try tomorrow and report back. Thank you.

Comment: Wow - this answer is perfect. I had to learn about deque objects and the yield feature - both of which are well worth learning. 
Unfortunately for me - I have to implement this in c code. I will need to create a FIFO list of subrange structs which will be far more difficult to implement in c. This emphasizes the power of python for this kind of problm. Anybody got any tips for me to implement in c?

Comment: @ZincX: I updated my answer with some hints.  Apologies for the non-obvious C code.

Comment: All I can say is wow! I actually went ahead and implemented your original algo in c and got it working but of course it uses a ton of code. This seconds solution works perfectly and is very elegant. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @ZincX: I finally found a version of the algorithm I'm satisfied with – see my second edit.

Answer (score 0):

[Binary Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) as array already has this structure. You might want to store your array in this form and print it sequentially. For node `i`, children are `2i + 1`, `2i + 2`.

Comment: The desired result is a pretty unusual form of binary heap (if you would at all call it thus): It would be a binary search tree stored in an array in the way you would usually store a binary heap.  However, tt does not fulfil the heap property, nor does this observation imply an easy way to construct this array.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... you're basically looking for some kind of space-filling curve of sorts. I'm almost certain that you can do that with clever bit-twiddling. You might like to take a look at the way indices are computed for the Morton Z-order or Ahnentafel indexing that's used in some cache-oblivious stencil algorithms. I had a look at this some years ago, and the indexing was similar to what you're describing and done with bit-twiddling.

Comment: A space-filling curve is a continuous function mapping one-to-one from an interval to the unit square.  How is this related to the question posed?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy for 1/2, right?

So why not do it recursively, so that 1/4 is 1/2 of 1/2, and 1/8 is 1/2 of 1/4?

Comment: *What* is easy for ½?  How do you terminate this algorithm?  How do you keep track of the numbers already consumed?

Comment: @SvenMarnach In a recursive solution you will divide the sequence into parts, which will then be subdivided, and so on. So there is no need to keep track of anything if you divide properly. Termination happens when the next division results in an empty sequence.

Comment: @HonkyTonk: The straight-forward recursive approach would yield the values in the wrong order.  I'm not sure what algorithm exactly you are talking about, but I can't think of an easy recursive solution.